# How to get the steam AppID by AppName in Steam WebAPI

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

So i'm trying to start a steamgame by entering the name of the game. For this reason I asked myself if it is possible to figure out the steam AppID through the entered name.

So I tried to collect the IDs through my steamApps folder without success.
I also found a website where you could search for the name of a specific game.

For example "https://www.steamgriddb.com/api/v2/search/autocomplete/grandtheftautov" returns a json with gtaIV and gtaV

The Problem with that is, that the stamAppID isn't found in the retrieved data.

Also I found an SQL Database (https://steam.internet.byu.edu/) where the steam name and the appID are found.
But this wouldn't be my prefered way to go, because the database is 17gb big.

Answer (score 4):

You use this API call: `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/`

```
{
    "applist": {
        "apps": [
            {
                "appid": 946180,
                "name": "The Gardens Between Soundtrack"
            },
            {
                "appid": 946190,
                "name": "Loveless cat"
            },
            ...
```

More info [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps#GetAppList).
The list is huge. Open it with a editor that can handle a huge file. You can search the JSON by name.

Answer (score 0):

If you save this into a file called playercount.sh and run it from a Linux terminal, you can accomplish exactly this.

```
#!/bin/bash    
#Example Usage:  ./playercount.sh "Left 4 Dead 2"    
appid=$(curl -s https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/ | jq ".applist.apps[] | select(.name==\"$1\")" | jq '.appid')    
curl -s https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/?appid="$appid" | jq '.response.player_count'
```