# Is there an API for getting the Steam AppID from just its name (AppName)?

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

I am working on a discord bot that gets the stats of a user given their SteamID64 and the AppID using the Steam API. Now, for the User id there is [this](https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) steam module for python that I am using with great success, but for the Game ID the user now has to enter the id "by hand" ex `!stats 730 user`, and I was wondering if there is some sort of API, that I wasn't able to find that would allow me to do something like this: `!stats csgo user`.

So far I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441606/how-to-get-the-steam-appid-by-appname-in-steam-webapi) but parsing such a huge amount of data every time is quite unpractical. I guess another *bad* solution would be to use [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/search/?a=app&q=csgo) and just use a web scraper to get the first item of the table returned when searching.

Comment: "*parsing such a huge amount of data every time is quite unpractical*" Pre-process it and cache the results, then.

Comment: Is the "csgo" in your example meant to be text entered by a user? If so it's not going to be very realistic without multiple names per each app entry to cover nicknames and the published name. You could split the JSON data into multiple files based on the first character in the name (numbers/symbols, letters) to help minimize the amount of data that needs to be loaded. Would either need a marker to track which characters are currently loaded or to load from a file every time.